# Regex -- Validação de uma string

Tags: regex

Boa noite pessoal,
Estou com dificuldade de formar um Regex que valide apenas a presença de letras minusculas e números.
Se alguém puder ajudar agradeceria muito!
Obrigado

Comment: simples assim [a-z0-9]

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-z0-9]*$
```

Explicação:

- `^` é a âncora que marca o começo de uma linha
- `$` marca o fim de uma linha
- `[a-z0-9]` guarda dentro de si os caracteres permitidos para casar `(letras minusculas e números)`
- `*` pode ter, não ter, ou ter vários, infinitos, ou seja, qualquer quantidade.

para acentuadas

```
/^[a-z\d\u00E0-\u00FC]*$/
```

OBS: `\d` é mesma coisa que `0-9`

Comment: Ajusta sua resposta pra aceitar acentuação.

Comment: põe no seu regex pra ficar mais completo

Comment: eu já indo Zzzz

Comment: Deixa queto. Vou lá. Abs!

Comment: 1. Dependendo a lib, para aceitar acentos é só por a flag `u` de unicode.
2. `[0-9]` pode ser escrito como `\d`